# AAPT: error in android on integrating third party library

Tags: android

***What I am trying to do***: [I am trying to integrate this library](https://github.com/Devlight/InfiniteCycleViewPager)

What I have done so far:

- I added cradle dependency  `implementation
  'com.github.devlight:infinitecycleviewpager:1.0.2'`
- I have cleaned , synched and built the project
- I added the xml as below

```
    <com.gigamole.infinitecycleviewpager.HorizontalInfiniteCycleViewPager
        android:id="@+id/swipableViewId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:icvp_interpolator="..."
        app:icvp_center_page_scale_offset="30dp"
        app:icvp_max_page_scale="0.8"
        app:icvp_medium_scaled="true"
        app:icvp_min_page_scale="0.5"
        app:icvp_min_page_scale_offset="5dp"
        app:icvp_scroll_duration="500"/>
```

**On building the project I get error:** `AAPT: error: '...' is incompatible with attribute icvp_interpolator (attr) reference.`

---

- I checked if the reference of `icvp_min_page_scale` is created. Looks
  like the reference is there

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr format="dimension" name="icvp_center_page_scale_offset"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="icvp_interpolator"/>
    <attr format="float" name="icvp_max_page_scale"/>
    <attr format="boolean" name="icvp_medium_scaled"/>
    <attr format="float" name="icvp_min_page_scale"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="icvp_min_page_scale_offset"/>
    <attr format="integer" name="icvp_scroll_duration"/>
    <declare-styleable name="HorizontalInfiniteCycleViewPager"><attr name="icvp_min_page_scale_offset"/><attr name="icvp_center_page_scale_offset"/><attr name="icvp_min_page_scale"/><attr name="icvp_max_page_scale"/><attr name="icvp_medium_scaled"/><attr name="icvp_scroll_duration"/><attr name="icvp_interpolator"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="VerticalInfiniteCycleViewPager"><attr name="icvp_min_page_scale_offset"/><attr name="icvp_center_page_scale_offset"/><attr name="icvp_min_page_scale"/><attr name="icvp_max_page_scale"/><attr name="icvp_medium_scaled"/><attr name="icvp_scroll_duration"/><attr name="icvp_interpolator"/></declare-styleable>
    <string name="app_name">InfinityCycleViewPager</string>
</resources>
```

---

**Question**: How to resolve this. Is there any setting in android studio we need to make or in project settings

Comment: https://github.com/Devlight/InfiniteCycleViewPager/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_vertical.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

> app:icvp_interpolator="..."

```
<com.gigamole.infinitecycleviewpager.HorizontalInfiniteCycleViewPager
        android:id="@+id/swipableViewId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:icvp_center_page_scale_offset="30dp"
        app:icvp_max_page_scale="0.8"
        app:icvp_medium_scaled="true"
        app:icvp_min_page_scale="0.5"
        app:icvp_min_page_scale_offset="5dp"
        app:icvp_scroll_duration="500"/>
```

or add default anim `@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator`

```
  <com.gigamole.infinitecycleviewpager.HorizontalInfiniteCycleViewPager
            android:id="@+id/swipableViewId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:icvp_center_page_scale_offset="30dp"
            app:icvp_interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
            app:icvp_max_page_scale="0.8"
            app:icvp_medium_scaled="true"
            app:icvp_min_page_scale="0.5"
            app:icvp_min_page_scale_offset="5dp"
            app:icvp_scroll_duration="500"/>
```